# Calling an element of a vector inside a function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I am new to Matlab and trying to define a simple function but keep running into an error. Details are:

1) V is a 31x1 vector;

2) The function mypi takes one input, which is a scalar (between 0 to 30). It finds the corresponding element in V vector and saves it in z.

3) Matrix A is a row vector with two elements 0 and z-10.

4) y, which is what I am interested in calculating is a linear function of the max of vector A.

Matlab, however, gives an error and is not recognizing element x in vector V. Can anyone please guide me how I should fix this problem? I will be grateful. Thank you.

```
function    y=mypi(x)
            z=V(x);
            A=[0, z-10];
            y=500+50*max(A);
end
```

Comment: where is `V(x)` defined? how does the function suppose to know `V(x)`?

Comment: Matlab arrays start from `1`, so `V(0)` will give you an error.

Comment: I should have clarified. I define the vector V just before defining the function as follows: V=linspace(0,30,31)

Answer (score 1):

you must pass `V` to `mypi` or make it visible to this function by defining it as `global`. But why bother passing both `V` and index `x` to this function instead of passing V(x) or z directly?

```
function    y=mypi(z)
            A=[0, z-10];
            y=500+50*max(A);
end
```

and call it by `mypi(V(x))`

Comment: Thank you. I will try doing this and give you an update.

Comment: Although `global` variables are one solution, they are probably the worst -- in particular at you coding level. Just pass the variable to the function as an additional input or -- as @FangQ showed here: make `mypi` applicable to vectors